# How to create a button using javascript that will call the function to edit the user input?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, frontend

The question is to get input from an HTML form and to check whether the inputs are entered and if inputs are entered correctly there should be two buttons called edit and send. in the edit button, I need to restore the input to form again and let the user edit

so now i have created the edit button but i dont know how to call the function in js`

```js
function formValidator(){
    var name = document.queryForm.name.value;
    var email = document.queryForm.email.value;
    var subject = document.queryForm.subject.value;
    var query = document.queryForm.query.value;
    
    if(name.length == 0){
        alert("Name cant be empty");
        return false;
    }
    else if (email.length == 0){
        alert("Email cant be empty");
        return false;
    }

    else if (query.length == 0){
        alert("Query cant be empty");
        return false;
    }

    else{

        document.write("Name       : " + name + "<br/>"); 
        document.write("Email      : " + email + "<br/>");
        document.write("Subject   : " + subject + "<br/>");
        document.write("Query      : " + query + "<br/><br/>");

        var editButton = document.write("<button onclick='editFunction'>edit</button>");
    }
}

function editFunction(){
    alert("edit is working");
}
```

```html
<!DOCRTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Query</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "FormStyles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>QUERY FORM</h1>
        <form name="queryForm" method ="POST" onsubmit="return formValidator()">              
            <label for = "name">Name</label><br>
            <input type = "text" id = "name" name = "name" placeholder="Type your name"><br><br>
            
            <label for = "email">Email</label><br>
            <input type="text" id = "email" name = "email" placeholder="Type your email"><br><br>

            <label for="subject">Select the query subjet</label><br>
            <select name="subject" id="subject">
                <option value="Delivery">Delivery</option>
                <option value="Delivery_cost">Delivery cost</option>
                <option value="Damaged_goods">Damaged goods</option>
                <option value="Over_charged">Over payed</option>
                <option value="Refund">Requesting for a refund</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select><br><br>

            <label for = "query">Enter your query here</label><br>
            <textarea name="query" id="query" cols="60" rows="10" placeholder="Brief  your query"></textarea><br><br> 

            <input type="submit" value="View query">
        </form>
        <script src="FormJs.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new HTML Button and add an event listener:

```
var b = document.createElement("button");
b.addEventListener("click", editFunction);
someHtmlElement.appendChild(b);
```